# Ejectutar funcion pasada por json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

tengo esta funcion de ajax:

```
function GuardarJson(url,que,id,cod,param,respuesta) {
    var Daticos = {id: id ,codigo: cod, respu: respuesta };
    $.ajax({
    url: "Paginas/"+url+"?que="+param,
        data: Daticos,
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            Alerta(data.alerta,data.Tipo,'');
            data.script
            },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){ $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error '+ xhr.responseText, sticky : true, type : 'error' }); }
    });
};
```

el caso es que desde json paso una serie de datos y uno de ellos es script dentro de script quiero pasar funciones a ejecutar variables para según que caso.

¿como puedo hacer que ese texto que paso por json se ejecute como funcion?

el formato que le estoy pasando es este:

```
$Respuesta['script'] = "$(\"#MenuIdFactura_".$Que."\").val('".$IdNuevo."').change(); alert('Holiii');";
```

las variables de la respuesta son porque esta dentro de una función de php pero al ejecutarse llegan con los datos bien puestos.

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres enviar scripts desde el servidor por ajax y ejecutarlos en el cliente?

Comment: si exactamente eso. @Einer

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de como te retorna el servidor el script? Asi seria mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: en este caso lo que estaria pasando es esto: $("#MenuIdFactura_InAlbaran").val('48').change(); alert('Holiii');

Comment: lo que pretendo que haga en este caso es que cambie el valor de MenuIdFactura_InAlbaran a 48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la funcion [`eval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) de javascript que evalua un string y lo ejecuta:

```js
eval('$("#input-id").val(4)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input-id" />
```

En tu caso solo le pasarias el string de la respuesta del servidor.

Ahora bien, [si buscas en internet](https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/151f1) sobre eval, veras articulos que prohiben su uso. Asi que en tu caso, lo que yo haría seria enviar el id del input, y el valor que le quieres asignar por medio a ajax y asi te ahorras enviar datos demás en las respuestas del servidor.

Por ejemplo digamos que ahora retornas el id del input y el valor, entonces solo cambiaras a esto:

```
function GuardarJson(url,que,id,cod,param,respuesta) {
    var Daticos = {id: id ,codigo: cod, respu: respuesta };
    $.ajax({
    url: "Paginas/"+url+"?que="+param,
        data: Daticos,
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
              $("#MenuIdFactura_"+data.id_input).val(data.nuevo_valor);
            },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){ $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error '+ xhr.responseText, sticky : true, type : 'error' }); }
    });
};
```

Comment: Pero el uso de eval es a nivel cliente ¿que podría inyectar del lado del servidor?

Comment: @Killpe No estoy a conocimiento de que pudiera pasarte en ese caso. Incluso antes de escribir esta respuesta, estaba considerándolo también. Ahora bien, si hay forma de evitar su uso seria lo recomendable. Cuando personas de alto nivel recomiendan evitarla, es porque su uso es peligroso. Repito, no se que puede pasar en tu caso, pero si lo evitas seria lo mejor.

Answer (score 1):

[Einer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126966/ejectutar-funcion-pasada-por-json#answer-126969) ya te ha dado la opción de usar `eval` así mismo te ha aconsejado refactorizar la lógica de tu negacio para que sigas buenas prácticas.

No obstante si aún después de todo lo que has leído hasta ahora aún deseas inyectar javaScript, también podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
;(function() {

var script = document.createElement('script')
var script_js = "alert('hola mundo')"

script.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(script_js)
)

document.body.appendChild(script)
document.body.removeChild(script)

}())
```

La lógica es simple, se crea un `HTMLElement` que coincida con `HTMLScriptElement`, a sí mismo se le inyecta el código a través de un elemento `Text`. Una vez creado el Script con el contenido a evaluar, se agrega al `DOM`  delegando la evaluacion del mismo. La evaluación es síncrona así que después de agregar al DOM (y por ende evaluarlo) se elimina del `DOM` (ya no es necesario)